# Bring movieclips that have been added through editor to front

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I have a game in which I have three different scenes. In the first scene, the objects (movieclips) were added through the flash editor, meaning that no actionscript was used to add them (not added with addChild). After that ive decided that I want to do the second and third scene entirely through actionscript and every object that is added is added with addChild(). The problem with this is that now the objects that have been added through actionscript appear in front of the ones added manually through the editor and I want it to be the other way around. I know that addChildAt() exists but I have over a 100 objects so it doesn't seem like a good option. In short: How do I set the Z-Indexes of movieclips that have been added through the flash editor and not through actionscript.

Answer (score 1):

At first I tell you, this is not a good practice.
I give you some methods:

1.add child at to the back of others:

```
addChildAt(myDisplayObject,0);
```

so your added children will go back.

2.set the index of display obects:
first you should give them instance names, then in code:

```
setChildIndex(myDisplayObect,myIndex);
```

so you set the index of your display object.

I   H☺ P E  this helps

Comment: Yes I know about those methods, as I said above.

Comment: @DimitarVelev - You don't really have any other options...  you could create a Sprite container and put that one container under all the timeline objects, then add your code created objects to the container.  I don't really see though why don't just use `addChldAt(object,0);` instead of `addChild(object)`, it's only 4 extra characters to type!

Comment: @ɫɬƚҭϻѦƝ - Beware though, when you tweak a timeline created object's parentage (eg you use addChild/addChildAt/setChildIndex) that object will no longer respond to timeline keyframes and will have to be manipulated through code from then on.   Best to use your option #1 and not #2 because of this.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis thanks for your information and thanks for your votes.